# Check whether two vectors contain the same (unordered) elements in R

Tags: r

I'd like to check whether two vectors contain the same elements, even if they're not ordered the same. For example, the function (let's call it `SameElements`) should satisfy these criteria:

```
SameElements(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 3))  # TRUE
SameElements(c(1, 2, 3), c(3, 2, 1))  # TRUE
SameElements(c(1, 2, 1), c(1, 2))  # FALSE
SameElements(c(1, 1, 2, 3), c(3, 2, 1))  # FALSE
```

Edit 1: Specified that function should return F when the vectors contain the same elements, but with different frequencies.

Edit 2: Cleaned up question to omit initial answer, as this is now in my actual answer.

Comment: How about `all(a %in% b)`. It basically answers the question *Are all the elements of `a` contained in the vector `b`?* If the values are unique then you could also use something like `anyNA(match(a,b))`

Comment: Ah good call, sorry wasn't clear here. I'm looking for F in that scenario (question edited for clarity).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In lieu of a cleaner alternative, here's the known solution:

```
SameElements <- function(a, b) return(identical(sort(a), sort(b)))
SameElements(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 3, 2))  # TRUE
SameElements(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 1, 3, 2))  # FALSE
```

Edit: `identical` instead of `all.equal(...) == T` per nrussell's suggestion.

Comment: Kind of splitting hairs, but `F <- function(a,b) identical(sort(a),sort(b))` will save you 3 keystrokes (the `==T`) from your `SameElements` function above - neat question though +1.

Answer (score 61):

I think you can use `setequal(a,b)`

**Updated update** `setequal` checks if two vectors are composed of the same elements but it does not check if these elements have the same occurrences in each vector.

Comment: setequal is new to me and look neat. +1

Comment: It's basically just `%in%` :)

Comment: Ya figured. Also it should be doing something extra since it is slower. But in terms of being a "cleaner alternative" it wins. hard to get any cleaner. :)

Comment: @RichardScriven, and both are basically `match` )

Comment: Well `setequal` is more like `all( sapply(a, "%in%", table=b) ) & all(sapply(b, "%in%", table=a) )`

Comment: Thanks, Marat, unfortunately I'm looking for vectors with the same frequencies. Question edited for clarity.

Comment: @BondedDust not exactly: `> setequal` returns `all(c(match(x, y, 0L) > 0L, match(y, x, 0L) > 0L))`. Moreover, `%in%` is also based on match:  `> %in%` returns `match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L`.

Comment: Same vector lengths isn't enough to satisfy the OP's requirements. Consider `setequal(c(1, 2, 1), c(1, 2, 2)) # [1] TRUE`

Answer (score 4):

You may be interested in the "compare" package. This answer demonstrates the `compare()` function, but for your case, you might do just fine with `compareIgnoreOrder()` (which matches almost exactly with your question's title).

There are several arguments that can be added as transformations that should be allowed in attempting to compare the elements. In the examples below (to save some typing), I've asked the function to allow all transformations (`allowAll = TRUE`) except for changing the vector length (`shorten = FALSE`).

```
library(compare)
compare(A1, A2, allowAll = TRUE, shorten = FALSE)
# TRUE
compare(A1, A3, allowAll = TRUE, shorten = FALSE)
# TRUE
#   sorted
compare(A1, A4, allowAll = TRUE, shorten = FALSE)
# FALSE
#   sorted
compare(B1, B2, allowAll = TRUE, shorten = FALSE)
# FALSE
#   sorted
compare(B1, A4, allowAll = TRUE, shorten = FALSE)
# FALSE
#   sorted
compare(A3f, A1, allowAll = TRUE, shorten = FALSE)
# TRUE
#   coerced from <numeric> to <factor>
#   sorted
```

Sample data:

```
A1 <- c(1, 2, 3); A2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
A3 <- c(3, 2, 1); A4 <- c(1, 1, 2, 3)
B1 <- c(1, 2, 1); B2 <- c(1, 2)
A3f <- factor(A3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

```
SameElements <- function (a,b){
  l <- Map(table,list(a, b)) # Compute frequencies - returns ordered table
  Reduce(identical,l) # Check if frequencies are the same for all input vectors
}

SameElements(c(1, 2, 3), c(1, 2, 3))  # TRUE
SameElements(c(1, 2, 3), c(3, 2, 1))  # TRUE
SameElements(c(1, 2, 1), c(1, 2))  # FALSE
SameElements(c(1, 1, 2, 3), c(3, 2, 1))  # FALSE
```

As you can see it works for any number of input vectors as long as you put them all in a list.

One liner:

```
Reduce(identical,Map(table,listOfVectors))
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needed some benchmarking, it seems that setequal is the best bet.

```
# testing speed of finding identical vectors
is_set_same1 <- function (a, b) {
  l <-
    Map(table, list(a, b)) # Compute frequencies - returns ordered table
  Reduce(identical, l) # Check if frequencies are the same for all input vectors
}
is_set_same2 <- function(a, b) {
  setequal(a, b)
}
is_set_same3 <- function(a, b) {
  all(a %in% b) & all(b %in% a)
}
is_set_same4 <- function(a, b) {
  require(compare)
  compare(a, b, allowAll = TRUE, shorten = FALSE)
}
is_set_same5 <- function(a, b) {
  return(identical(sort(a), sort(b)))
}

library(microbenchmark)
a <- 1:1000
b <- 1000:1
# microbenchmark()

microbenchmark(setequal(a, b), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(all(a %in% b) & all(b%in%a), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(is_set_same1(a, b), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(is_set_same2(a, b), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(is_set_same3(a, b), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(is_set_same4(a, b), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(is_set_same5(a, b), times = 1000L)

b <- 2000:1001
microbenchmark(setequal(a, b), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(all(a %in% b) & all(b%in%a), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(is_set_same1(a, b), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(is_set_same2(a, b), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(is_set_same3(a, b), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(is_set_same4(a, b), times = 1000L)
microbenchmark(is_set_same5(a, b), times = 1000L)
```

OUTPUT -------------------

```
> library(microbenchmark)
> a <- 1:1000
> b <- 1000:1
> # microbenchmark()
> 
> microbenchmark(setequal(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
           expr   min    lq     mean median   uq   max neval
 setequal(a, b) 18.84 19.83 21.27717  20.45 21.4 46.77  1000
> microbenchmark(all(a %in% b) & all(b%in%a), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
                          expr   min    lq     mean median    uq  max neval
 all(a %in% b) & all(b %in% a) 19.94 20.94 22.35695 21.525 22.78 43.1  1000
> microbenchmark(is_set_same1(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
               expr     min       lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
 is_set_same1(a, b) 619.391 642.6005 697.5008 656.131 701.286 12438.7  1000
> microbenchmark(is_set_same2(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
               expr    min      lq     mean median    uq      max neval
 is_set_same2(a, b) 19.211 20.1155 22.57942  20.68 21.53 1312.921  1000
> microbenchmark(is_set_same3(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
               expr  min   lq     mean median    uq      max neval
 is_set_same3(a, b) 20.3 21.7 28.30276  22.73 26.73 2343.473  1000
> microbenchmark(is_set_same4(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
               expr    min       lq     mean median       uq      max neval
 is_set_same4(a, b) 280.73 291.2955 321.6352 302.69 317.1455 10151.83  1000
> microbenchmark(is_set_same5(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
               expr   min    lq     mean median     uq      max neval
 is_set_same5(a, b) 30.85 32.56 37.04722 33.355 35.625 2089.263  1000
> 
> b <- 2000:1001
> microbenchmark(setequal(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
           expr   min      lq     mean median     uq   max neval
 setequal(a, b) 9.811 10.5005 11.21262  10.84 11.405 33.89  1000
> microbenchmark(all(a %in% b) & all(b%in%a), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
                          expr   min    lq     mean median      uq   max neval
 all(a %in% b) & all(b %in% a) 17.24 18.72 20.43695  19.44 20.4495 71.54  1000
> microbenchmark(is_set_same1(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
               expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq      max neval
 is_set_same1(a, b) 740.26 763.526 822.8048 791.371 829.346 12382.05  1000
> microbenchmark(is_set_same2(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
               expr   min      lq     mean  median     uq   max neval
 is_set_same2(a, b) 10.26 10.9495 11.70339 11.3295 11.915 36.83  1000
> microbenchmark(is_set_same3(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
               expr    min    lq     mean median    uq   max neval
 is_set_same3(a, b) 17.491 18.55 19.91781  19.29 20.28 38.98  1000
> microbenchmark(is_set_same4(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
               expr     min      lq    mean   median      uq      max neval
 is_set_same4(a, b) 652.792 683.286 743.621 696.5465 744.246 11116.88  1000
> microbenchmark(is_set_same5(a, b), times = 1000L)
Unit: microseconds
               expr  min      lq     mean median      uq     max neval
 is_set_same5(a, b) 30.9 32.2955 35.00967  34.34 35.7445 116.931  1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically your problem can be outlined in those steps :

```
if not same unique values: return FALSE
else if same Frequencies: return TRUE
    else return True
```

In proper R code :

```
SameElements = function(v1, v2)
{
  tab1 = table(v1) ; tab2 = table(v2)
  if( !all(names(tab1) == names(tab2)) ) return(FALSE) # Same unique values test
  return(all(tab1==tab2)) # Same frequencies test
}
```

Some examples :

```
v1 = c(1, 2, 3)
v2 = c(3, 2, 1)
SameElements(v1, v2) # TRUE as both uniqueness and frequencies test are verified

v1 = c(1,1, 2,3)
v2  =c(3,2,1)
S
```

ameElements(v1, v2) # FALSE as frequencies test is violated

PS : i) You can replace `!all()` by `any()`
~~~ii) To speed up the code you can quickly return `FALSE` when the two vectors don't
~~~have the same length, thus avoiding frequencies computation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an improvement regarding performance.

- Yes, `setequal` outperforms other approaches when we can expected that vectors have the same length (see answer from @Daycent). I did a more extensive benchmark that [can be accessed as gist](https://gist.github.com/SigurdJanson/3e87c7cfda032d313ab04748556ac911) if anyone is interested.
- Additionally, the question indicates that vectors can vary in length. In this case it is faster to add a check in length, first. It adds a negligible overhead for equal length vectors and outperforms `setequal` by far **if the lengths may differ**.

```r
# testing speed of finding identical vectors
library(bench)

is_set_same7 <- function(a, b) {
  length(a) == length(b) && setequal(a, b)
}
```

Case: Total overlap, different order

```r
a <- 1:1000
b <- 1000:1
bench::mark(
  setequal(a, b),
  `length/set` = is_set_same7(a, b)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 setequal(a, b)   17.3µs   22.1µs    28938.    46.5KB     17.4
#> 2 length/set       17.8µs   21.7µs    35033.    39.8KB     24.5
```

Case: No overlap

```r
b <- 2000:1001
bench::mark(
  setequal(a, b),
  `length/set` = is_set_same7(a, b)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 setequal(a, b)    8.5µs   10.4µs    72885.    19.9KB     29.2
#> 2 length/set        9.2µs   11.4µs    64277.    19.9KB     25.7
```

Case: length difference by 1, same elements except first

```r
b <- a[-1]
bench::mark(
  setequal(a, b),
  `length/set` = is_set_same7(a, b)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 setequal(a, b)    8.9µs   10.9µs    71672.    19.9KB     28.7
#> 2 length/set        500ns    700ns  1341436.        0B      0
```

Case: One vector is `NULL`

```r
b <- NULL
bench::mark(
  setequal(a, b),
  `length/set` = is_set_same7(a, b)
)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 setequal(a, b)    1.9µs    2.1µs   300661.    3.95KB     30.1
#> 2 length/set        600ns   1000ns   853760.        0B      0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>