# Count # of IDs that meet both criteria

Tags: r

I have a dataset that has two columns. One is userid, the other is company type, like below:

```
    userid      company.type
    1               A
    2               A
    3               C
    1               B
    2               B
    3               B
    4               A
```

I want to know how many unique userid's there are that have company.type of A and B or A and C, (but not B and C).

I'm assuming it's some sort of aggregate function, but I'm not sure how to place the qualifier that company.type has to be A and B or A and C only.

Comment: You could transform to wide format `reshape2::dcast(data, userid ~ company.type)` and then compare columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an idea with `dplyr`. `setequal` checks if two vectors are composed of the same elements, regardless of ordering:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(userid) %>%
  summarize(temp = setequal(company.type, c("A", "B")) |
              setequal(company.type, c("A", "C"))) %>%
  pull(temp) %>%
  sum()

# [1] 2
```

**Data:**

```
df <- structure(list(userid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), company.type = c("A", 
"A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A")), .Names = c("userid", "company.type"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

See: [Check whether two vectors contain the same (unordered) elements in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27912800/check-whether-two-vectors-contain-the-same-unordered-elements-in-r)

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Do you have a good resource for learning the powers of dplyr? I read about it a lot but haven't had much experience with it.

Comment: @deslaur If you haven't already, you can start with this: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/dplyr.html

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `base R` using `table`

```
tbl <- table(df1) > 0
sum(((tbl[, 1] & tbl[,2]) | (tbl[,1] & tbl[,3])) & (!(tbl[,2] & tbl[,3])))
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sort `DF` and reduce it to one row per userid with a `types` column consisting of a comma-separated string of company types. Then filter it using the indicated condition.  Finally use `tally` to get the number of rows left after filtering.  To get the details omit the `tally` line.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>% 
  arrange(userid, company.type) %>%
  group_by(userid) %>% 
  summarize(types = toString(company.type)) %>% 
  ungroup %>%
  filter(grepl("A.*B|A.*C", types) & ! grepl("B.*C", types)) %>%
  tally
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 1
      n
  <int>
1     2
```

### Note

The input used, in reproducible form, is:

```
Lines <- "userid      company.type
    1               A
    2               A
    3               C
    1               B
    2               B
    3               B
    4               A"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines,  header = TRUE)
```